# Unable to set bokeh plotting parameters using BOKEH + HOLOVIEW plotting option via Python

Tags: plot, backend, bokeh, curve, holoviews

Is there any documentation specifying how to pass Bokeh parameters via holoview?
I am reading the tutorials but I think there is something small I have missed.
There is an example online which describes this in Ipython but I am trying to do it via a python WITHOUT Ipython notebook.
http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Bokeh_Backend.html?highlight=bokeh

When I run this program I get the curves but the color does not change and I also get this error: WARNING:root:Curve01537: Setting non-parameter attribute style={'line_color': 'green'} using a mechanism intended only for parameters

How can we set the parameter?

```
    Code Example here
    from pprint import pprint, pformat
    import holoviews as hv
    import numpy as np
    import pathlib, os
    import webbrowser
    import lasio, las
    from holoviews import Store
    from holoviews.plotting.bokeh.element import (line_properties, fill_properties, text_properties)

   def plot_bokeh(plot):

       #Create renderer instance
       myrenderer = hv.Store.renderers['bokeh'].instance(fig='html')
       out_file_name = "".join(["./OUTPUT/","gyro", "_graph.html"])
       with open (out_file_name, 'w') as f:
       #Plot static html
           f.write (myrenderer.static_html(plot))
       f.close()
                     webbrowser.open_new_tab(pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(out_file_name)).as_uri())


    def holoview_sandbox():


      curve_opts = dict(line_color='green')
      xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)
      data = (xs, np.sin(xs))


      holo_plot = hv.Curve(data, label='MY LABEL' , style=curve_opts) 
      plot_bokeh(holo_plot)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        holoview_sandbox()
```

Answer (score 2):

In HoloViews the options aren't bound to the objects themselves, which has various benefits including being able to plot with different backends. The pure-Python way of setting style options is this:

```
  curve_opts = dict(line_color='green')
  xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)
  data = (xs, np.sin(xs))
  holo_plot = hv.Curve(data, label='MY LABEL')(style=curve_opts)
```

The [Options Tutorial](http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Options.html) describes how to set options like this, but please let us know if you found some of that unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works as well

> holo_plot.opts(style={'color': 'green'})

When you change the entry 'line_color' to 'color' in the dict() of Philipp's answer, then this works for the matplotlib backend as well.

Details about setting options can also be found [here](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html) in addition to Philipp's link.